# Dimension of subspace with zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra

If the only solution to linear transformation T (x) = 0 is x=0, then why is the dimension of the kernal not 1 and why is it 0

Comment: The set $\{0\}$ is not linearly independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, think of dimension as the length of the list explicitly addressed in a $\text{span}$ that is linearly independent.

The basis of $\{0\}$ is $\varnothing$, which we might indicate with $\text{span}()$.  The number of elements in a span of zero elements is zero, so the dimension of a space described by such a span is also zero.

This should make sense, since 0 can be the result of an infinite number of linear combinations of an arbitrary number of terms, and therefore there are no vectors which form a basis for {0}, because of the complete lack of linear independence.  No vectors to form the basis of a space $\iff$ no vectors listed in the $\text{span}$ of that space.